# Krull dimension of the ring of holomorphic functions on an almost complex manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Can the Krull dimension of the ring of holomorphic functions on an almost complex manifold be non-zero and finite?

Can the $\mathbb{C}$-algebra of holomorphic functions on an almost complex manifold be isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[[z]]$?

The almost complex structure [cannot](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0723086917300154) be integrable. The simplest smooth manifold to consider is probably the unit ball of real dimension 4.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the MO question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/94537/what-is-the-krull-dimension-of-the-ring-of-holomorphic-functions-on-a-complex-ma.  I would think that the answers to your questions are 'no', since, if there is a nonconstant holomorphic function $f$ on the almost-complex manifold $M$, then the set of all $h\circ f$ (where $h$ is any holomorphic function $h$ on $\mathbb{C}$) forms a subring, and this subring already will already have infinite Krull dimension, won't it?

Comment: Krull dimension is not necessarily increasing for inclusions of rings

Comment: If we consider the subalgebra $\mathbb{C}[x, xy, xy^2, \ldots]\subset \mathbb{C}[x, y]$ I think it has infinite Krull dimension.

Comment: Though Dr. Bryant's remark would seem to rule out the polynomial ring in one variable.

Comment: @Nguyen:  It can't be $\mathbb{C}[z]$, since, if $z$ is a non-constant holomorphic function on $M$, then $\mathrm{e}^z$ will be a non-constant holomorphic function on $M$ that does not belong to $\mathbb{C}[z]$.

Comment: @Nguyen:  I notice that you have now deleted your second question, which asked whether the ring could be $\mathbb{C}[z]$.